# How do I configure spork to create more than 2 processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

By default Spork on Windows creates 2 processes. How do I configure it so that it spawns more processes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally buckled and forked the spork project. The line to change to spawn more than 2 slave processes in Spork is simple:

In lib/spork/run_strategy/magazine.rb, change

```
Slave_Id_Range = 1..2
```

to

```
Slave_Id_Range = 1..10
```

or whatever number you feel is appropriate.